# Optimising an ActiveRecord count query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Record table with columns named item_id and key. Item_id is a foreign key pointing to a table named Item. Active model definition looks like as follows:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end
```

Now I want to count how many records belongs to each item with distinct keys, the result should look like

```
{
    #<Item id: 1, ...> => 19,
    #<Item id: 2, ...> => 6,
    #<Item id: 3, ...> => 21,
    #<Item id: 4, ...> => 33,
}
```

I can do this in two lines with a Hash object counting:

```
records = Record.select('DISTINCT item_id, key').includes(:item)
records.each_with_object(Hash.new 0) { |e, a| a[e.item] += 1 }
```

I am wondering if it is possible to make it using pure active record queries or SQL statements.

Answer (score 6):

```
Record.count(group: "item_id")
```

OR

```
Record.select("item_id, COUNT(*) as count_all").group("item_id")
```

UPDATE: In your situation you can count records with distinct keys like below

```
Record.select("item_id, COUNT(DISTINCT key) as count_all").group("item_id")
```

Comment: This seems not what I want since it includes duplicated keys for an item in count.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either with ActiveRecord like this (you get the count by calling `.record_count` on each item record):

```
Item.
 select("items.*, count(records.id) as record_count").
 joins("left join records on records.item_id = items.id").
 group("items.id").
 all
```

Or you can use [4.1.2.4 :counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) if you don't need to specify any conditions.